# How to create a graph of largest strongly connected component

Tags: python, networkx

I want to create a graph of largest strongly connected component of a directed graph.
Networkx has a function ([components.strongly_connected_components](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected_components.html)) that can extract a largest strongly connected component, but it only returns a generator of sets of nodes.
But this doesn't contain the connection between nodes.

Is there any function that can create a directed graph of largest strongly connected component?

Comment: see:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strongly-connected-components/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [docs for extracting a subgraph](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html).

You can get the edges of the subgraph containing those nodes.

In this simple example, nodes 2, 3, and 4 are strongly connected, but node 5 is disconnected (completely).

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([2, 3, 4, 5])

G.add_edge(2, 3)
G.add_edge(4, 3)
G.add_edge(4, 2)
G.add_edge(3, 2)
G.add_edge(3, 4)
G.add_edge(2, 4)

# following results in [{2, 3, 4}, {5}]
strongs = sorted(nx.strongly_connected_components(G), key=len, reverse=True)
for strong in strongs:
    print(G.subgraph(strong).edges())
```

Result (first line is for `{2, 3, 4}`, and the second line is for `{5}` which has no edges):

```
[(2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 2), (3, 4), (4, 3), (4, 2)]
[]
```